ELK - How to add my own rule action variable?
I am trying to use an ELK security rule, to pass an action event that updates an index (threat-ip). The available variables to pass in, are not too useful.  I want the variables captured in the rule matching (such as source.ip or threatintel.indicator.ip).
I have tried to add these in the JSON object, but they will always come through as empty values.
Clicking on the available rule variables, I get a list, but nothing close to what I'm going for:
Screenshot of rule variables available
